# How to make an SSRS parameter = a field from another dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting-services, parameters

I am writing an SSRS report to create an invoice.

In my report, I have a dataset whcih runs the following query:

```
select Customer, Name, BillAddress, BillCity, BillState, BillZip from ARCM where ARCM.Customer = @BillCustomer and ARCM.CustGroup = 1
```

As you can see, I have a parameter called '@BillCustomer'.

I have another dataset which runs this query:

```
select Co, Customer, Invoice, TransDate, DueDate, PayTerms, CustRef  from ARBH
Where Invoice = @Invoice
```

How can I change my report so that @BillCustomer does not need to be manually entered when I run the report however, it gets its value from the Customer field in the second dataset?

[image: Example]

Comment: You may need to increase your browser zoom to read the text in the above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change your `Customer` dataset to use the parameter `@Invoice` directly and change the query to

```
select Customer, Name, BillAddress, BillCity, BillState, BillZip 
from ARCM where ARCM.Customer IN (
select Customer 
from ARBH
Where Invoice = @Invoice) and ARCM.CustGroup = 1
```

Or using `JOIN` in above query.